# Blockly is not rendered in component

Tags: angular, angular8, blockly

When generating component to show blockly inside it, it's not rendered. I have done it all by the documentation and also tried to different solutions but still no use.

I've tried to create container in *.ts file and then use .appendChild, i tried to use @ViewChild to select template element, Renderer2 as well.

main template

```html
<div class="row h-100">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 mb-3 h-50">
     <div class="row h-50">
       <div class="col h-100">
           <app-game-wizard-points></app-game-wizard-points>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row h-50">
       <div class="col h-100">
         <app-questions-list></app-questions-list>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 mb-3 h-100">
     <app-game-wizard-blockly></app-game-wizard-blockly>
   </div>
</div>
```

So this is my blcokly.component.html

```html
<div id="blocklyDiv"></div>
```

And this is some sequences from my component.ts file

```js
ngOnInit() {

    this.workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
      toolbox: `<xml>
        <category name="Logic">
          <block type="lq_if"></block>
          <block type="logic_operation"></block>
          <block type="logic_negate"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Conditions">
          <block type="lq_time_condition"></block>
          <block type="lq_task_finished"></block>
          <block type="lq_task_finished_how"></block>
          <block type="lq_compare_variable"></block>
          <block type="lq_track"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Actions">
          <block type="lq_show_on_map"></block>
          <block type="lq_show_in_list"></block>
          <block type="lq_activate"></block>
          <block type="lq_deactivate"></block>
          <block type="lq_finish"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Tasks">
        <block type="lq_all_tasks"></block>
        <block type="lq_tasks_range"></block>
          ${this.wizard.points.controls.map((point, i) =>
            `<block type="lq_task_${i}"></block>`
          )}
        </category>
      </xml>`
    });

    this.workspace.toolbox_.flyout_.autoClose = false;
```

The output in Chrome Inspect is

```html
<div _ngcontent-qtd-c5="" id="blocklyDiv"></div>
```

The expected result is to display blockly in the main component where are multiple components rendered

Answer (score 0):

Try delaying the inject using setTimeout().

```
ngOnInit() {

setTimeout(() => {
    this.workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
      toolbox: `<xml>
        <category name="Logic">
          <block type="lq_if"></block>
          <block type="logic_operation"></block>
          <block type="logic_negate"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Conditions">
          <block type="lq_time_condition"></block>
          <block type="lq_task_finished"></block>
          <block type="lq_task_finished_how"></block>
          <block type="lq_compare_variable"></block>
          <block type="lq_track"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Actions">
          <block type="lq_show_on_map"></block>
          <block type="lq_show_in_list"></block>
          <block type="lq_activate"></block>
          <block type="lq_deactivate"></block>
          <block type="lq_finish"></block>
        </category>
        <category name="Tasks">
        <block type="lq_all_tasks"></block>
        <block type="lq_tasks_range"></block>
          ${this.wizard.points.controls.map((point, i) =>
            `<block type="lq_task_${i}"></block>`
          )}
        </category>
      </xml>`
    });
}, 0);

}
```